# Webdriver execution is not working (Webdriverexception) is given

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, testng

I have written a very basic script to just login to an application and logout. The script stop working as soon as it logs in to the application and an exception is given and I cant figure out the reason for this. This is the script.

```
public class Login {

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String url = "http://xxxxxxxxx";

@Test
public void login_class() {

    driver.get(url + "/Web/guest/login.aspx");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("xxxxx@gmc.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("xxxxx123");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
    driver.get(url + "Web/guest/home/default.aspx");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(
            By.cssSelector("span.menu-icons-sprite.menu-icon-signout"))
            .click();

}

@BeforeTest
public void create_driver() {

    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}

@AfterTest
public void exit() {

    driver.quit();
}
```

}

And the exception given is followed

FAILED: login_class
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 5.10 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'xxxxx-PC', ip: '10.0.0.192', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 1e311cd0-34d1-4dd2-9cde-e52cbb9fb52e
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=42.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
    at bileetaTest.Login.login_class(Login.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'xxxx-PC', ip: 'xxxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.get(file:///C:/Users/xxxxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3548365288572112291webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10523)

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I have to add another "/" before the Path I had provided.

Comment: Why are you navigating like this. why dont you click the home button instead ?

Comment: The home button is in a separate menu and I just thought of doing it this way.. no special need and practically I will be clicking on the home button later.

Comment: If that url changes you have to change the code. But if you click the home button then no need to change your code. Thats the advantage of clicking the home button